# html anchor tag going across the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, anchor

I am creating a basic HTML site - while doing this I have noticed that my anchor tags() are going all the way across the screen with a black background - this is a footer as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <title>Under construction</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="app/stylesheets/stylesheet.css">

        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/JS/app.js"></script>

 </head>



 <body>


  
 <div class="container">
  <div ng-view>
   
  </div>
 </div>



        <div id="footerDiv" class="footBackground">
<hr>
             <a href="" target="_blank">
                <div ng-init="imgsrc ='app/images/linkedin.png'" ng-mouseover="imgsrc='app/images/linkedinHover.png'" ng-mouseout="imgsrc='/app/images/linkedin.png'">
                    <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" width="50" height="50" class="footLinkedIn"></img>
                </div><br />
            </a>

        <a href="" target="_blank"><h5><span>Website created by <br />Adam parker</span></h5></a>
<hr>
        </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I can have tried so many times - to get rid of the extended anchor tag but I everything I have tried is not working.

I've tried editing the anchor tag via CSS but it still doesn't work 
It's also a short line of code, so I don't understand why it is going over half-way across the screen. Could somebody help please?

PS. I have removed code - however all the code that was removed was commented out for the moment while I was working on the footer, I just wanted to remove the anchor tag being too long.

Comment: i don't see the anchor tag "going all the way across the screen with a black background"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You anchor tags enclose the entire div, which runs right across the width of the page. Just reverse the order.

```
<div ng-init="imgsrc ='app/images/linkedin.png'" ng-mouseover="imgsrc='app/images/linkedinHover.png'" ng-mouseout="imgsrc='/app/images/linkedin.png'">
  <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/pub/adam-parker/101/29/910" target="_blank">
    <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" width="50" height="50" class="footLinkedIn" />
  </a>
</div>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/g7weehnc/3/)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - that one works perfectly, it is however the link below that with the text "Created by Adam Parker".

Comment: @apark - same reason but with your <h5/>s. I've updated the fiddle.